# Authentication API for Angular.js App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

I use AngularJS to build Single Page App. I want the code AnggularJS section always check the auth situation, always send with the headers information [X-Access-Token] whenever there is a connection to take data to server. The belows is the code I used, but it might have problem somewhere because It does not work. I have to add data of header X-Access-Token by hands into function $http get, post. Do you have any experiences of AngularJS, pls help me! Thank you.

```
app.factory('myHttpResponseInterceptor',['$q','$location',function($q,$location){
return function (promise) {
    var success = function (response) {
        return response;
        console.log(response);
    };

    var error = function (response) {
        if (response.status == 401) {
            //$state.go('signin');

        }

        return $q.reject(response);
    };

    return promise.then(success, error);
};
}]);

//Http Intercpetor to check auth failures for xhr requests
app.config(['$httpProvider',function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpResponseInterceptor');
}]);


app.factory('api', function ($http, $cookieStore, flash, $state) {
return {
  init: function (token) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['X-Access-Token'] = token || $cookieStore.get('token');
  }
};
});

app.run(function (api) {
  api.init();
});

app.controller('adminProCatController', function($scope, $rootScope, flash, $state, $http, $cookieStore) {

    $http.get('api/v1/categories?image_size=50x50', {headers: {'X-Access-Token': $cookieStore.get('token')}}).success(function(data) {
        $scope.categories = data;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Recognize an authenticated user

There are probably several ways to recognize an authenticated user; infact it’s possible to set a global variable, or create a cookie… but my favourite way to reach the objective is to use an AngularJS service.
This approach give me several advantages.
The first advantage is strictly related to the real nature of each AngularJS service; services are singletons, so there is only one instance of each service… and this allow to share data between different views, controller, directives, filters, and others services, without the need to overpopulate the global scope.

You can refer to this [article](http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/deal-with-users-authentication-in-an-angularjs-web-app)

Or you look for complete solution - [git](https://github.com/fnakstad/angular-client-side-auth)